# How to capture the status 302 URL redirect on Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am making a `http.post()` that returns a 302 redirect but I cannot find the way to capture the URL of the redirect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect should be at the response header, under [`location`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) field.

The header is available from the response callback, as [explained here](http://strangemilk.com/access-http-response-headers-angularjs/).

Comment: Thank you for response @GuyYogev for your answer but unfortunately is not working for me.  I am using angular 4 this is my code and the headers are empty:
                                                                             
this.http.post(basePath+'/uaas/signin/'+provider,"")
      .subscribe((resp: Response) => console.log(resp.headers)),
                      (error:Response) => console.log("Error"+(error.headers));

Comment: I'll have another go at it :).

Maybe you'll need to explicitly ask for the [full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response).